# update scope object with filter - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to update assign filtered objects from `$scope.Departments` to `$scope.FilteredDepartments` on change text field.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="searchItems(searchquery)" ng-model="searchquery">
```

AngularCode:

```
$scope.Departments= [{id: 1, name:'ABC'},{id: 2, name:'XYZ'}...];

$scope.searchItems = function (searchString) {
    //Need to do something here
}
```

How do I filter with name and assign filtered result to `$scope.FilteredDepartments` ?

Thanks for help

Comment: What exactly will you do with $scope.FilteredDepartments? Is it just to show the filtered result to the user?

Comment: u mean $scope.FilteredDepartments = $filter('filter')($scope.Departments, searchString) ?

Comment: @JohnyStark I will update pagination of bootstrap with that.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchValue">
<h3>Filter Ones</h3>
<div ng-repeat="department in filteredDepartments">
    <p>{{department.name}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.departments= [{id: 1, name:'ABC'},{id: 2, name:'XYZ'}];

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.searchValue;
}, function () {
    $scope.filteredDepartments = $filter('filter')($scope.departments, $scope.searchValue);
});
```

don't forget to inject $filter into the controller